# What is the transition matrix for this process?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

[image]

For the Markov process with transition diagram shown
above, I am wondering why I can expect (without any computation) the steady state to
have equal probabilities for the four states A;B;C;D,
no matter what the probabilities r, s and t happen to
be. [As is the normal convention, missing arrows all
represent transitions with probability zero.]

**Is this because the four states $A,B,C,D$ have no difference between them at all? (i.e.they have equal positions?)** The steady state vector will just be 1/4 1/4 1/4 1/4?

**Secondly, I am also wondering how to write out the transition matrix for this process.** May I ask for some help for that? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The states are very similar. Every state has the same probabilities to stay, to get back to the previous state and to step forward to the next state. We have to imagine the chain as the following sequence of states $\cdots \rightleftarrows \overset {\curvearrowleft }A\rightleftarrows \overset {\curvearrowleft }B\rightleftarrows \overset {\curvearrowleft }C\rightleftarrows \overset {\curvearrowleft }D\rightleftarrows \overset {\curvearrowleft }A\rightleftarrows\cdots$

The transition matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
r&s&0&t\\
t&r&s&0\\
0&t&r&s\\
s&0&t&r
\end{bmatrix}$$

where a row represents the current state and a column represents the next state.

Indeed, by computation, $\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac14$ are the stationary probabilities:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
r&s&0&t\\
t&r&s&0\\
0&t&r&s\\
s&0&t&r
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac14\\\frac14\\\frac14\\\frac14\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac14(r+s+t)\\\frac14(r+s+t)\\\frac14(r+s+t)\\\frac14(r+s+t)\end{bmatrix}$$
and $r+s+t=1$.

Comment: Is there a way to write out the explicit transition matrix（I mean with specific numbers)? Or that is just impossible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Do you mean, for example, $r=s=t=\frac13$?

Comment: What I mean is whether the transition matrix can be further specified? Or the best we can do is to give the general form of the matrix like what you did.

Comment: Yes. No need to further specify the matrix. Everybody can substitute any triplets of numbers that add up to one and are positive. (Like  $r=s=t=\frac13$)

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much.